# MySQL Subquery Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, subquery

I can´t see any error but who knows.

This query works:

```
select distinct id_mat_bauteil from material_bestueckungslinien E where exists(
                    select id_mat_bauteil from(
                                select id_mat_bestueckungslinie from (
                                    select id_mat_bestueckungslinie, id_material from material_musterbestueckungen A
                                    union all
                                    select id_mat_bestueckungslinie, id_material from material_sonderbestueckungen B) C
                                where C.id_material = 10154) D
                    where D.id_mat_bestueckungslinie = E.id_mat_bestueckungslinie)
```

But if I extend this query with another subquery it gives me an error:

```
Select * from  material_bauteile Z
    where exists (
        select distinct id_mat_bauteil from material_bestueckungslinien E where exists(
                select id_mat_bauteil from(
                            select id_mat_bestueckungslinie from (
                                select id_mat_bestueckungslinie, id_material from material_musterbestueckungen A
                                union all
                                select id_mat_bestueckungslinie, id_material from material_sonderbestueckungen B) C
                            where C.id_material = 10154) D
                where D.id_mat_bestueckungslinie = E.id_mat_bestueckungslinie) F
        where F.id_mat_bauteil = Z.id_mat_bauteil)
```

Error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'F where F.id_mat_bauteil = Z.id_mat_bauteil)' at line 10

Comment: Replace the last 2 lines with `where D.id_mat_bestueckungslinie = E.id_mat_bestueckungslinie) AND id_mat_bauteil = Z.id_mat_bauteil)`

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have given an alias to the subselect used for the EXISTS clause which is not required, then used another WHERE clause (ie, your *select distinct id_mat_bauteil* has 2 WHERE clauses).

Further you SELECT id_mat_bauteil from a sub select that doesn't return this field. However that issue applies to both your old and your updated statements

Having a play with what I think you are trying to do, something like the following may be more efficient:-

```
SELECT DISTINCT z.* 
FROM  material_bauteile Z   
INNER JOIN material_bestueckungslinien E 
ON Z.id_mat_bauteil = E.id_mat_bauteil
INNER JOIN (SELECT id_mat_bauteil FROM material_musterbestueckungen WHERE id_material = 10154
            UNION 
            SELECT id_mat_bauteil FROM material_sonderbestueckungen WHERE id_material = 10154) C
ON E.id_mat_bauteil = C.id_mat_bauteil
```

Note this is assuming that the field id_mat_bauteil is on *material_musterbestueckungen* and *material_sonderbestueckungen* and matches on that with *material_bestueckungslinien*